# Is there a command for separated lines for each word in a \blank in xsim?

Tags: exercises, xsim

I want to print a cloze with `xsim`, but instead of one complete line for the gap I want a line that indicates how many words there have to be.

Of course it's doable by giving each word an extra blank,

```
\blank{more} \blank{than} \blank{one} \blank{word}
```

but I would prefer to have a

```
\blank*{more than one word}
```

achieving the same.

I still want to use the normal `\blank` command as well, so it should be an extra comment, not a rewrite of the existing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea for a custom command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xsim}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_acep_words_seq
\seq_new:N \l_acep_blank_words_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \acep_blank_words:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_acep_words_seq {~} {#1}
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l_acep_blank_words_seq \l_acep_words_seq
      { \xsim_blank:n {##1} }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_acep_blank_words_seq {~}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \blankwords {m}
  { \acep_blank_words:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

more than one blank word

\blankwords{more than one blank word}

\end{document}
```

[image]