# Hyphenation and strange line breaks with xsim \blanks

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, exercises, xsim

I have a problem with the line breaks using `\blank` from the xsim package.

As shown in the following picture the line breaks, even if there would be way enough space to finish it at both questions (and I do have way more in my document with the same problem so solving it by putting in `\\` per hand isn't my preferred solution).

Also I was wondering if it shouldn't be able for `\blank` to break the lines between the words (not somewhere in the word)as it is possible to teach it to gap the underline at those points? (see for example here [Is there a command for separated lines for each word in a \blank in xsim?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389783/is-there-a-command-for-separated-lines-for-each-word-in-a-blank-in-xsim)) So that a blank for a single word doesn't break at all and blanks for more then one word break between the words.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[clear-aux]{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]}
  {}

\xsimsetup{
    exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. , 
    blank/scale = {2},
    exercise/template=item,
    solution/template=item,
    path = {exercises}
}

\newenvironment{frag}
  {\description}
  {\enddescription}


\begin{document}


 \begin{frag}

     \begin{exercise} 
        The blind master acts as a \blank{happy bunny} to the whole team and kindergarden, advocating a holistic and longword approach to replacement.
    \end{exercise}

     \begin{exercise} 
         The blind scholar \blank{provides}, \blank{provides}, \blank{teaches}, and \blank{provides}.
     \end{exercise}



\end{frag}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is using `\blank` inside a list like `description` and it is arguably a bug in the implementation of the command

Comment: @clemens  I use it in the `description` as that is the way shown in the handbook and/or examples to get the look of a list for the exercises without the name. I tried it by declaring a template like `\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate {test} {\GetExerciseProperty {counter} \nobreakspace}{}` (not a nice look yet) instead of using the `description` environment. But trying this I have still similar line breaking problems. So to me it seems like having nothing to do with the `description` (even in the default environment is the same problem) (not with the first but with the second and others)

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in v0.10 (2017/09/19) of `xsim` (at the cost of a somewhat cluttered log file):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  blank/scale = 2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[1.] The blind master acts as a \blank{happy bunny} to the whole team and
    kindergarden, advocating a holistic and longword approach to replacement.
  \item[2.] The blind scholar \blank{provides}, \blank{provides}, \blank{teaches}, and
    \blank{provides}.
\end{description}

The blind master acts as a \blank{happy bunny} to the whole team and
kindergarden, advocating a holistic and longword approach to replacement.

The blind scholar \blank{provides}, \blank{provides}, \blank{teaches}, and
\blank{provides}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: super, that solves the first part of the problem. Thanks so far, do you have a solution for the second part of the question as well? Or should I perhaps post that as a separate question?

Comment: The second “problem” sounds like a feature request but to be honest I didn't really understand it. Anyway, feature requests should be discussed on the github repository.

Comment: I specified the problem a bit, but yes it is rather a feature request and not shown in the examples. I will prepare a MWE and all when I have more time again. - But sorry I don't know anything about the github repository, what and where is that, that I can ask my question there?

Comment: @acep it is the url on the first page of the manual and is also mentioned on CTAN's entry for `xsim`